# Why is tostring not a method of lxml.etree._Element

Tags: python, lxml

When I have a lxml.etree._Element it seems natural that I should be able to call its tostring() method to get the element representation as a string. I then have to remind myself that I need to ask the etree module to do this for me.

```
from lxml import etree
xml_string = '<a><b>test</b></a>'

tree = etree.fromstring(xml_string)

#No! - why not?
tree.tostring()

#Yes
etree.tostring(tree)
```

So my question is, why was the library designed so that the first approach (`tostring`) doesn't work. I was hoping there was some obvious design decision I could learn from. Additionally, is there an `_Element` method that accomplishes `tostring`?

Comment: Perhaps `tostring` requires information from the current state of the document in order to correctly interpret a fragment (e.g. namespaces, doctype, etc)?

Comment: I think you can basically get wherever (parent, siblings, etc.) from an element. Instead the design is such that you need to use a utils like function of the module (`etree`) that I wouldn't expect to hold any instance/state information. This is so unexpected that I feel like I'm missing something - thus the question. Almost tempted to submit a feature request -- although wondering if I'm just missing an existing "attribute"/method of the element that has/generates this info (like `.text` -- note `.text` exists but is something different than what `tostring` returns)